# hideSplashScreen method in IBM MobileFirst v8 deprecated

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working through the upgrade process from V7.1 to 8.0 -- hybrid application and after the scan I see that `WL.App.hideSplashScreen` has been deprecated

What should I use instead to get the same action in IBM MobileFirst v8?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Cordova's SplashScreen plugin https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

To make sure the splash screen doesn't hide automatically set the `AutoHideSplashScreen` in the config.xml to `false` i.e., `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />`

Then call `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` to hide the splash screen.

Comment: @user2570135 if this answered your question please mark it as correct so that others know if the have the same question. Thanks